# Why am I getting "local variable referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python, pandas, variables

I'm trying to create new columns from a list by adding a number after each item in that, but I'm getting this error.

I've tried to declare the list as a "global variable" but it doesn't work.

```
colunasPes = ['numeroOrdem', 'nome']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colunasFam+colunasPes, index = range(len(lista)))

def criaColunas(i):#cria novas colunas no df para um novo membro
    for i in len(colunasPes):
        i = str(i)
        colunasNova[i] = colunasPes[i]+i
        colunasPes = colunasPes + colunasNova
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colunasFam+colunasPes, index = range(len(lista)))

criaColunas(1)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'colunasPes' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `columnPes` is a global variable. To use it inside the function, add `global columnPes` inside the function

Comment: This code would not give that error. You would get the UnboundLocalError for colunasNova, because you have not defined it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colunasPes = colunasPes + colunasNova` introduces a new variable also called `colunasPes` just in the scope of the function, which you are therefore referencing before assignment

You could mark it as `global` in the function.

```
def criaColunas(i):
    global colunasPes
    for i in len(colunasPes): #replace i? why pass it in?
        i = str(i)
        colunasNova[i] = colunasPes[i]+i
        colunasPes = colunasPes + colunasNova
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colunasFam+colunasPes, index = range(len(lista))) #this may not do what you want either
```

Or pass it in?

```
def criaColunas(i, colunasPes):
    # exactly as before

criaColunas(1, colunasPes)
```

By the way - you are passing in `i` and then changing it in the `for` loop. Is that intentional?

Furthermore, you seem to be trying to change another variable in your function that isn't in scope.

Try returning the dataframe instead?

```
def criaColunas(i, colunasPes):
    global colunasPes
    for i in len(colunasPes): #replace i? why pass it in?
        i = str(i)
        colunasNova[i] = colunasPes[i]+i
        colunasPes = colunasPes + colunasNova
    return pd.DataFrame(columns = colunasFam+colunasPes, index = range(len(lista))) 

df =     criaColunas(1, colunasPes)
```